# GPE for Juno overwrites arguments in run config

Tags: google-eclipse-plugin, gwt-2.5, google-plugin-eclipse

I'm using GPE (GWT 2.5 plugin) on Eclipse Juno and it looks like the content of the arguments tab gets overwritten each time I perform the apply button. Only workaround is to edit the arguments tab last and then close the dialog. I have to set a different port number, but the port attribute gets deleted as mentioned above. I don't use embedded server.

TIA
ujbi

Answer (score 0):

What port number are you setting? If you're setting it to the default port number expected for that server, it will be removed from the Arguments tab.

Have you tried changing the port number in the Launch Config UI? There should be a tab for "Server", where you can change the port.

Answer (score 0):

@Rajeev

I dont't use the default port (8888) and I dont' want to use the embedded server, so this is not checked in the 'server' tab. The application is running on a JBoss Server on port 8080.
When I add this via '-port 8080' in the 'Arguments' tab it will be romved mostly.